# Reuse AngularJS controller logic

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, model-view-controller

This is the code of one controller from my application, in the User page.

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/Users/GetUsers').success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});

this.search = function () {
    $http.post('/Users/SearchUser', $scope.search).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}

this.delete = function() {....}
}]);
```

On another page, the Permission page, I create a controller with the same logic

```
app.controller('PerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/Permission/GetPermissions').success(function (data) {
    $scope.data= data;
});

this.search = function () {
    $http.post('/Permission/SearchPermission', $scope.search).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}

this.delete = function() {....}
}]);
```

As you can see, the only different is the URL. How can I reuse the logic from a controller to another?

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) are for.

So instead of:

```
$http.get('/Permission/GetPermissions').success(function (data) {
    $scope.data= data;
});
```

You'd call something like:

```
permissionsService.get().then(function (data) {
    $scope.data= data;
});
```

---

And:

```
this.search = function () {
    $http.post('/Permission/SearchPermission', $scope.search).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

Replaced with something like:

```
this.search = function () {
    searchService.search().then(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

etc...

Generally, all server calls should be in services anyway, so there's a great opportunity to improve your code *and* learn how to do it right.

Comment: I know about the service, but if I use the service, I still have to declare the "search, delete" in each controller.
What I want is create a parent controller, other controller inherit from it, and I only need to configure the url for Get and Search, Delete .... or something like that.

Comment: Well then, create a service that does all that for you... It's really a job for a service rather than a controller.